# No module named bumpy

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

i am new mac user and new to python.

i just install python 2.7 and matplotlib and try to run this demo code:

```
"""
Simple demo with multiple subplots.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)

y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'yo-')
plt.title('A tale of 2 subplots')
plt.ylabel('Damped oscillation')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r.-')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Undamped')

plt.show()
```

when i click Run -> Run Module i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mehmetalinadigulec/Desktop/subplot_demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

i searched for hours but can`t fix it.

i edit my ~/.bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}"
export PYTHONPATH
```

and result

```
echo $PYHTONPATH
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:
```

Comment: `numpy` is not part of Python's standard library.  Did you install it correctly?

Comment: I, uh... assume `bumpy` is a typo in your title?

Comment: please Google the **title** you wrote before asking.

Comment: http://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/
i install python and matlablib using this instruction.
and 
/usr/local/bin/idle to open python idle than open .py file and run.
it works..

Answer (score 1):

The simply answer would seem to be to install numpy via http://www.scipy.org/install.html